# Wrong reminders badge on macOS Sierra

Tags: dock, reminders

My Reminders dock badge shows 6 reminders (am using macOS Sierra 10.12.3)

[image]

But there are only 2 due:

[image]

I already tried:

- Closing Reminders, killing the Dock, reopening Reimenders
- [Enabling the Debug menu and refreshing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/262592/reminders-badge-shows-wrong-count-on-different-devices)

Reminders are synced with iCloud and Exchange, all other devices have the right count of open reminders.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you tried "force quit" (alt+click) reminders?

Comment: Yes it's the only way to quit. The application does not respond

Comment: You didn't mention this information in your question - app doesn't respond. Are reminders synced via iCloud? Do you also see the same error on other devices with what your iCloud is synchronised? Have you tried restarting your machine?

Comment: Sorry, I mixed two questions I had on AskDifferent. Sorry, Reminders is responding and working normally.

Comment: If you've figured out what is the issue feel free to answer your own question or delete it because you've mixed two questions.